# How to perform teardown for a specific Thread Group

Tags: jmeter

is there a way to create a teardown for a specific Thread Group in Jmeter? That is, the object "tearDown Thread Group" seems to be executed at the end of each Thread Group in the test. It's possible to bind a tearDown only with a single Thread Group? If not, is there an other object to insert in the Thread Group to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)) so it's sufficient to put your "teardown" logic to the "bottom" of the Thread Group and the relevant Samplers will be executed "last".

Few more hints:

- If you need to run your main logic for several iterations - put it under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)
- If you need to run your main logic for specific time - put it under the [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)
- If you need to pass some data between Thread Groups you can use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)

[image]

Comment: Yes, but if my Thread Group is stopped, for example, by a Duration set in the Thread Group, I want to execute some samplers even if the Thread is stopped before to execute the last samplers. For example, in my Thread Group I have a Loop Controller that runs infinite time, and it is stopped only by the "duration" parameter. When the Thread Group is stopped, I want to execute some samplers as a teardown, but if I put these as "last" they are not executed.

Comment: Let me repeat loud and clear: remove duration and loops from the Thread Group and use Loop Controller and/or Runtime Controller